# In Intellij, how do I replace the front of a line?

Tags: regex, replace, intellij-idea

Here's a screenshot of what I attempted:

[image: screenshot]

Shouldn't replacing `^` mean, "replace the front of every line"?  I don't understand why this is not working.  If I replace `$` it replaces the end.  Perhaps this is a bug?  I'm using Intellij 12.1.6 and Windows 7.

If I replace `^S` it grabs the "S" from the 2nd and 3rd line.  I wish it grabbed the first line, too.  But that's kind of like saying, "I wish this bug worked better".

Comment: If you are determined to the result (and like simple solutions) use `Edit -> Column selection mode` (`ALT-SHIFT-INS` on Linux/Windows), select all rows in a cursor in the first column and type `"`.

Comment: @Szpak nice, that's a neat trick

Answer (score 1):

This replacement seems to work well with a more recent version (tested with community version 13.0.6 for linux). This is probably a bug with your version.